# Suppose that $V$ is a vector space. Show that if $U$ and $W$ are vector subspaces of $V$, then $U∩W$ is also a vector subspace of $V$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose that $V$ is a vector space. Show that if $U$ and $W$ are vector subspaces of $V$, then $U∩W$ is also a vector subspace of $V$.

- This seems obvious, I am just unsure as to how to write this out as a proof or general explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $0\in U$ and $0\in W$, $0\in U\cap W$.
Let $(v_1,v_2)\in (U\cap W)^2$ and $\mu\in k$, since $U$ is a vector subspace of $V$ and $v_1,v_2\in U$, one has $v_1+\mu v_2\in U$, likewise $v_1+\mu v_2\in V$. Hence $v_1+\mu v_2\in U\cap W$. Therefore, $U\cap W$ is a vector subspace of $V$.

**N.B** Let $V$ be a $k$-vector space and $W\subset V$. $W$ is a vector subspace of $V$ if and only if $0\in W$ and: $$\forall (w_1,w_2)\in W,\forall\mu\in k,w_1+\mu w_2\in W.$$

Comment: This makes sense, thank you very much.